# sparql how to filter according to the date range

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, rdfs

I have the following filters that filters my data to the item in the **last week**.

```
#just consider the likes in the last one week.
  filter (?ratingDate >= "2017-03-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime )
```

as you see i set the dateTime of the last week in my hand (hard coded), is there a way to set this date automatially?

I'm looking for something like **now-7day**

Comment: There is the `now()` function: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-now

Comment: @CaptSolo thanks that is definately benefial, i would like also to ask if there is such a function in owl not just in sparql ?

Comment: @CaptSolo okay but please how can I say now - 7 days ?

Comment: OWL is a language to model data and has no concept of functions.

Comment: @AKSW that i know, and i wanted to say, but i forgot, i meant that if there is a way to put a constrain using the now or the year of the current date, it sounds that there isn't, and it is okay, i just want to know how to make that in sparql, the `now()` is (i think) good but how can I use it please to say `now()-7days` or if there is any other way to check if a giving date is within the a range of maximum 7 days of today

Comment: @Ania some sparql endpoints may support arithmetic functions on dates. I don't recall whether it's mandatory on the spec, but I think that jena does support it. But that's still at the sparql level. As captsolo said, there are no functions in owl,it's not that kind of language

Comment: xsd:dateTime comparison is required by the SPARQL spec, thouhg no other date or time related types and not full arithmetic. . To do "now()-7 days" needs xsd:durations. Apache Jena 3 has a fairly complete set of xsd datatypes and F&O operations on atomic values (no XML sequences) including "dateTime - duration". i.e `now()-"P7D"^^xsd:duration`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor could you have a look on this when you got free time please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914679/why-protege-doesnt-infer-a-data-property-in-this-case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(consolidating the comments)

**now - 7 days** requires a number of things:

There is a function in SPARQL for the current point in time: `now()`

"7 days" is an xsd:duration, `"P7D"^^xsd:duration`

"-" is arithmetic involving an xsd:dateTime and an xsd:duration -- the operation is op:subtract-yearMonthDuration-from-dateTime (from "XPath and XQuery Functions and Operators") -- and also overloading the "-" operation to dispatch to that function.

You need to check with the SPARQL engine you are using as to whether the extension of xsd:dateTime and an xsd:duration arithmetic is supported.

Once you have the calculated xsd:dateTime for "now - 7 days", the ">=" comparison of a part of standard SPARQL:

```
FILTER ( ?ratingDate >= (now()-"P7D"^^xsd:duration) )
```